# window.close() not working after url change

Tags: javascript

When I use window.open() to open a window, and then window.close() to close it, all works flawlessly. But if I go to different url (for example go to google.com) in the child window (while its opened), it cannot be closed using the window.close() anymore. It only works in chrome. Is there a way to solve this please?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="open"></button>
    <button id="close"></button>

    <script>
      var win;
      $("#open").click(function() {
        win = window.open();
      });
      $("#close").click(function() {
        win.close();
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can edit your code to a working snippet (to demonstrate your problem) by using `<>` in the toolbar.